# Angular.js $resource result

Tags: angularjs

I found very strange behavior of Angular $resource. Please checkout following lines of code:

```
    class Service
        constructor: ($resource) ->
            service = $resource '/record/:id'

            Service::list = (cb) ->
                service.query().$promise.then (data) ->
                    #result: data == [e, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
                    cb data

            Service::get = (id, cb) ->
                service.get(id:id).$promise.then (data) ->
                    #result: data == {id: 1, name: 'name' ...}
                    cb format data
```

Service "get" method returns correct value (object) sent by server, but the "list" method as result return array which contains $promise and $resolved...

Does anyone has some logic explanation?

UPDATE:

I found the problem. Service result is array of strings and that cause as result array of sting chars. This can be solved by using $http instead of $resource.

Ex:

server-side -> ['list', 'of', 'elements']

client-side -> ['l','i','s','t']

Answer (score 5):

If like me you'd like your response to give you the data without the extra $promise and $resolved attributes you can modify the resource and add an 'interceptor' as described here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#resource-promises-are-resolved-with-the-resource-instance

For a get it will look like this:

```
var Resource = $resource('/url', {}, {
  get: {
    method: 'get',
    interceptor: {
      response: function(response) {
        // expose response
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can access the response object rather than the resource instance when you make a get request. For example:

```
Resource.get(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key){

    }, $scope.varName);
});
```

This also means you can access other response attributes like `response.status`, `response.headers` as well as getting the instance of the resource with `response.resource`.

Answer (score 2):

> but the "list" method as result return array which contains $promise and $resolved

Double check this--the way Chrome displays arrays inside a `console.log` when the array has extra properties is misleading. For example, try the following in the Chrome console:

```
> a = [1, 2, 3]

> a.$promise = 'thing'

> a.$resolved = true

> a
  [1, 2, 3]

> console.log(a)
  [1, 2, 3, $promise: "thing", $resolved: true]
```

As you can see, it lists `$promise` and `$resolved` as elements of the array, even though they're not actually *in* the Array.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Thank you for helping and hint about Chrome inspector, but  the problem is caused by response from server...

Comment: Do you have any sources for why this is? It's VERY misleading when trying to debug responses.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) itself mentions about this and it's usage

> The Resource instances and collection have these additional
>   properties:
>
> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>   collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy
>   to use in resolve section of $routeProvider.when() to defer view
>   rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is resolved with the http response object,
>   without the resource property.
>
> $resolved: true after first server interaction is completed (either
>   with success or rejection), false before that. Knowing if the Resource
>   has been resolved is useful in data-binding.